# A potential role is a full-time position. How do I go about convincing them that a contract is better?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, contracts, fulltime

I've been primarily a contractor the last few years, as it affords me travel in-between contracts.

Now a really good role is coming up, and it's a perm position.  It's a good job, but I really would prefer a 6-9 month contract.

Should I try convincing them to change to a contract instead, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Tough. They have decided that they need a perm, and now you come along (the unknown person) telling them 'they have it wrong'. I'm interpreting now, but that's exactly what people do. Whatever you do try to prevent that interpretation, stick to 'I do not want to work full time' and is there a way we can meet halfway?

Comment: ... well why should it be contract instead of permanent? Obviously someone in the company thinks having someone as a full-time permanent hire is better than contract.

Comment: To the commentors, sorry, guess it wasn't clear. I'm not saying they're wrong, just that I personally would prefer a contract.  I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess the answer is simple, then... either convince them you are awesome enough they should change their expectations/wants to match your interests or convince them having a contract position is actually better for their company.

Answer (score 4):

It will be a pretty tough sell. They want a permanent person - presumably because this is a role that will be responsible for ongoing work, and they want someone to grow into it and take ownership of the responsibilities.

You're basically saying "hey, I'm more expensive, and I'm going to take off and make you look for someone else in 6-9 months".

As enderland said in a comment, if you can convince them that you are awesome enough, this might be possible. Particularly if they don't have much luck finding anyone similarly awesome who wants to take the permanent position.

Ultimately it's a negotiation. Asking for a contract when they want a permanent employee is like asking for $x+y salary when they only want to pay $x. If they want you bad enough, they might agree - if they don't, they won't.

The danger in this sort of negotiation is that if you ask for the 6-9 month contract and they say "no", they might not be interested in offering you permanent role either any more. They might - quite reasonably - assume that you're not likely to stick around beyond 6-9 months if you take it.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unusual situation where for the first time in years, I'm considering sticking around in a city. But on the other hand, if I decide after 6 months that this city isn't for me, I'd want to move on.

Comment: Permanent employees have been known to leave after 6-9 months, so if you think you might want to stick around, take the job and let later worry about itself.